# cannot reshape array of size 89401 into shape (299,299,3)

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to convert my PNG image (299,299) to RGB (299,299,3) for a long time, I tried a lot of suggested methods but  I haven't been successful. I'm sending an image from postman to my pycharm fastapi my images are GREYSCALE PNG x-ray images

> code:

```
 
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

app = FastAPI()


MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../saved_models/1")

CLASS_NAMES = ["COVID", "Lung_Opacity", "Normal", "Viral Pneumonia"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    image = image.reshape(299,299,3)
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

    predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

I'm doing this for the first time and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help. the error i'm getting is

> cannot reshape array of size 89401 into shape (299,299,3)

Comment: Where does `read_file_as_image` come from and what does it do? What format is your image? (E.g. file format, colour depth, RGB or greyscale, etc.) And what is the text of the error message you get, including the stack trace?

Comment: 299*299*3 is much bigger than 89401, right?  You need to figure out why `image` is that size?  Maybe the file is corrupted, or you haven't read all of it.  Apply some logic to the problem!  `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements in the array.

Comment: read_file_as_image is an np.ndarray where  image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data))) my image is greyscale png  the error is ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 89401 into shape (299,299,3)

Comment: You should add that information to the question, that way it's easy for everyone to see. The same with the other things I asked.

Comment: 89401 is exactly 299*299. It sounds like the file was read correctly but only has one channel. Perhaps it is an indexed palette image or perhaps it is greyscale.

Comment: i tried image = cv2.resize(image, (299,299,3))  but i got Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get 3 channels [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
image = np.dstack([image.reshape(299,299)]*3)
```

Or if you want only one channel

```
image.reshape(299,299)
```